# Android Studio Google Map application no longer displays map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've been working on an small application for a project that's meant to display the user's location and track them as they move around, also letting them display markers. This was working perfectly fine up until today where I booted up the application and find that it doesn't display the map anymore. The Google logo displays at the bottom of the page along with the zoom options but the map itself never loads. Here's the code for my Map activity.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

  private GoogleMap mMap;
  LocationManager locationManager;
  private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
  Marker mMarker;
  LocationListener locationListener;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
      // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
      SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
              .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
      mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
      locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
      {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
      }
      locationListener = new LocationListener() {
          @Override
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              double latitude = location.getLatitude();
              double longitude = location.getLongitude();
              //get the location name from latitude and longitude
              Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
              try {
                  List<Address> addresses =
                          geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                  String result = addresses.get(0).getLocality()+":";
                  result += addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                  if (mMarker != null){
                      mMarker.remove();
                      mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                      mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(21);

                  }
                  else {

                      mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                      mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(21);
                      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20.0f));

                  }

              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

          }
      };
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 0, locationListener);
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 0, locationListener);
  }




  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
      mMap = googleMap;
      mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json));
      //Setting Map zoom controls to be enabled
      mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
      mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
      mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener(){
          public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng){
              //creating marker
              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
              //set marker position
              markerOptions.position(latLng);
              //set latitude and longitude on marker
              markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude+ " : " + latLng.longitude);
              //clear the previous click position
              mMap.clear();
              //add marker on map
              mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
          }
      });

  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
  }
}
```

This is the error message I get on repeat once the maps activity is run

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
        at com.example.pubapp.MapsActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MapsActivity.java:65)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:371)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:300)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Like I said this app was running perfectly fine last night, and I haven't really changed anything since then other than adding a couple currently unused activities. I've already tried changing the API key, using a new emulator and doing a fresh install on android studio but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: "I haven't really changed anything since then *other than*" is probably what caused the behaviour. Revert all your changes and check again. If it works, check step by step what caused the bug. Usually API keys are creating such problems, so maybe double-check them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I took a look at my maps API key and couldn't see anything wrong, but deleted the current one and made a new one anyway. The original one didn't have any restrictions on it, so I added some to the new one, although it still won't display the map. I also made an entirely new basic maps project to test if I was just creating the key wrong, but the map won't even show up on that.

Comment: Okay, if a basic sample does not work you may just have some facepalm bug. Closely read the logoutput. The Maps library usually gives good error output, but sometimes it is formatted inconspicuously. Watch out for request limit, api key info, initialisation stuff and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Opened the project today to find that rebooting my PC has solved the issue, no more errors showing up and map is displaying as normal.